# Using multiprocessing.pool in a loop and update target function

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a quick question about python Multiprocessing.pool. Here is my code:

```
import multiprocessing as mp 

info =999
def func(x):
    global info
    print info
    return x**3

pool = mp.Pool()
for i in range(2):
    print "Iteration: ", i
    results = pool.map(func, range(1,10))
    print "Value of info", info
    info += 1
    print results 
    print "Iteration", i, "End"
    print
```

And the output looks like this:

```
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
Iteration:  0
Value of info 999
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
Iteration 0 End

Iteration:  1
Value of info 1000
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
Iteration 1 End
```

I am wondering why in the second iteration, 999 is printed again instead of 1000. How can I update global variable info so that 1000 will be printed in the second iteration? Thank you so much!

Comment: Hmmm I don't understand, you say that on the second iteration, 999 is printed, but I see 1000? Furthermore, you are using `info -= 1`, so I would *expect* `info == 998` on the second iteration...

Comment: sorry, the the code should be info+=1. So a total of eighteen 999 are printed. But as I updated info in the for loop, i expected the last 999 to be 1000. Since func prints info.

Comment: But fundamentally, each process has it's own set of globals. If you wish to share state, then read about [your options in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#sharing-state-between-processes). Sharing state is a non-trivial proposition. Note, `multiprocessing` is essentially a threading-like interface wrapping the `subprocess` module. Literally, a seperate Python process get's created for each worker, hence multi-*processing*

Comment: Thank you so much!. I will look into it

Answer (score 2):

Comments have already explained a bit. I guess I will explain a bit more.

When using `multiprocessing` module, it will create new processes per requested number of processes in `pool`. Default is calculated by `multiprocessing.cpu_count()`.

Let's say the script you wrote is `A.py`, which created process `A`. When `A` creates new processes, they are called child processes of `A`. These child processes will have the same global variables with `A` to start with.

However, each child process has individual scope, therefore changing variable `info` in one child process does not affect the values of `info` in other child processes. And it certainly will not affect the values in parent process `A`.

A simple solution is to instruct each child process to report required changes of `info` to parent process `A`. That is, each child process in `map` should return `-1` as result, and parent process `A` aggregate the updates in its own scope. In distributed computing, this is called parameter server design.

In an ideal world, what you really want is threading, which shares scope and memory. But `Python` threading can get very complicated because of `Global Interpreter Lock`. You can do some Google search on this if you are interested.

---

I was misreading your code. In my mind at 2am I read modification of `info` in children and printing in parent. In fact that is the reverse.

You are correct that the point is modification is not shared across processes. The child processes will not be aware of the change if you are using `global` to access `info` in child process, because the function is `pickled` at creation time of the module. You can read on at http://grahamstratton.org/straightornamental/entries/multiprocessing

You need to send it the dynamic `info` as an argument of the function, like so:

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def dual_input(t):
    info, x = t
    print info
    return x**3

def main():
    info =999
    pool = mp.Pool(2)
    for i in range(2):
        print "Iteration: ", i
        results = pool.map(dual_input, zip([info]*9, range(1,10)))
        print "Value of info", info
        info += 1
        print results
        print "Iteration", i, "End"
        print


if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

The above code prints:

```
Iteration:  0
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
999
Value of info 999
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
Iteration 0 End

Iteration:  1
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
1000
Value of info 1000
[1, 8, 27, 64, 125, 216, 343, 512, 729]
Iteration 1 End
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer. So in terms of the above code, I guess the child thread doesn't change global variable "info". But process A increments "info" by 1 during the iteration. However, in the second iteration, the child process will stick with the initial value of "info", which is 999. That's why 999 is being printed. Is this right?